# Ionic app is not running is android studio emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I cannot run my ionic app in android studio emulator. when i am using `ionic run android`. It shows

`

> myApp1@0.0.1 ionic:build D:\workspace\cordova\myApp1

```
> ionic-app-scripts build
[12:45:20]  ionic-app-scripts 2.0.2
[12:45:20]  build dev started ...
[12:45:20]  clean started ...
[12:45:20]  clean finished in 5 ms
[12:45:20]  copy started ...
[12:45:20]  transpile started ...
[12:45:22]  transpile finished in 1.93 s
[12:45:22]  preprocess started ...
[12:45:22]  deeplinks started ...
[12:45:22]  deeplinks finished in 11 ms
[12:45:22]  preprocess finished in 12 ms
[12:45:22]  webpack started ...
[12:45:22]  copy finished in 2.08 s
[12:45:27]  webpack finished in 5.11 s
[12:45:27]  sass started ...
[12:45:27]  sass finished in 691 ms
[12:45:27]  postprocess started ...
[12:45:27]  postprocess finished in 6 ms
[12:45:27]  lint started ...
[12:45:27]  build dev finished in 7.78 s
[12:45:29]  lint finished in 1.73 s
D:\workspace\cordova\myApp>
```

`

I am using cordova 5.0.0 and ionic 2.2.3. How it possible to run on emulator. I have tried for long time. So please help me.

Comment: have you create any emulator

Comment: yes i create android studio emulator. but it's not working. my adb commands also not working

Comment: can you test on real device

Comment: my real device also not connecting. I am using windows 10. when i use `emulator -list-avds` it shows the list of avds. so it works emulator command.

Comment: use ionic build android command , it will generate apk in your platforms -> android ->build-> outputs ->apk folder ,then  manually copy apk on your real device .

Comment: il is not generating apk file. That is my problem.

Comment: check your sdk path is correct or try to use other sdk

Comment: my sdk path is correct how to use other sdk

Comment: I am using latest sdk.

Comment: download another sdk and give its path on your android variable

Comment: create dummy project and try to run it on real device  .

Comment: not working dummy project. i am trying to change sdk.